# Using dplyr to sort a table by two alphanumeric columns

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)  

Data <- tibble(
      Area1 = rep(c("A1 1AA", "B3 4TT","D1 1AA", "A10 6TY","A2 9GG"),2),
      Area2 = c("A2 7BB", "B11 5TT","A14 9SS","A4 4HH","V6 9FF", "A11 6TT","B4 3DD","D1 4FF","G5 7DD","A2 7YY"))
```

I would like to sort it by `Area1` and then `Area2`, however `arrange` does not produce the desired result because it's in lexicographical order.

```
Data %>% arrange(Area1,Area2) #not the desired order
```

Is there a way using `dplyr` to produce this output that is in the desired order?

```
Output <- tibble(
      Area1 = c("A1 1AA", "A1 1AA", "A2 9GG","A2 9GG","A10 6TY","A10 6TY", "B3 4TT","B3 4TT","D1 1AA","D1 1AA"),
      Area2 = c("A2 7BB", "A11 6TT","A2 7YY","V6 9FF","A4 4HH", "G5 7DD","B4 3DD","B11 5TT","A14 9SS","D1 4FF"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another option using `arrange()` and `str_sort()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

Data %>%
  arrange(across(starts_with("Area"), ~match(.x, str_sort(unique(.x), numeric = TRUE))))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   Area1   Area2  
   <chr>   <chr>  
 1 A1 1AA  A2 7BB 
 2 A1 1AA  A11 6TT
 3 A2 9GG  A2 7YY 
 4 A2 9GG  V6 9FF 
 5 A10 6TY A4 4HH 
 6 A10 6TY G5 7DD 
 7 B3 4TT  B4 3DD 
 8 B3 4TT  B11 5TT
 9 D1 1AA  A14 9SS
10 D1 1AA  D1 4FF
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like we can use `mixedorder` with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtools)
library(stringr)
Output2 <- Data %>% 
              slice(mixedorder(str_c(Area1, Area2)))
```

---

Or another option is to remove the numeric, non-numeric separately and use that in `arrange`

```
Output3 <- Data %>%
    arrange(str_remove_all(Area1, "\\d+"), 
            readr::parse_number(Area1),
            str_remove_all(Area2, "\\d+"), 
           readr::parse_number(Area2))
```

-checking with OP's expected

```
identical(Output, Output2)
#[1] TRUE

identical(Output, Output3)
#[1] TRUE
```